# Maven: hide source generation dependency from consumers

Tags: java, maven

I'm using Maven to build a library that uses code generation techniques to generate some source code and then compiles the source code (along with some handwritten code) and outputs a JAR for other projects to consume.

When I then require the library from an application, Maven downloads all the transitive dependencies specified in the library's POM, including dependencies that are only used during code generation and are not required for run-time.

Is there a way to tell Maven not publish all the dependencies as transitive dependencies - just the ones that are required for the runtime?

### Configuration Details

The library has multiple (non-test) source folders:

- `src/main/java` - here lives the custom code the library exposes.
- `src/main/generator` - here lives the code generator code that isn't exposed by the library.

The Maven POM file has all the dependencies that are supposed to be exposed as part of the library API ("transitive dependencies", as AFAIU, using the 'compile` scope), in the main section, and in addition has two profiles:

- `generate-code` - this profile overrides the source director to the generator source dir, the output directory to a custom `target/generator-classes` directory, and also adds dependencies needed just by the generator code. It then runs the maven compiler in the `generate-sources` phase and then uses other plugins to run the code generation.
- `build` - this profile builds the generated sources from the `target/generated-sources` (where the code generation puts them) as well as the main Java source files, and outputs a JAR.

Unfortunately, if I then run `mvn deploy`, the resulting versioned POM file in the repository includes the entire thing including the generator dependencies in the generator profile, and consuming projects will then download all the generator dependencies as well, put them in the classpath, and when you shade the consumer's JAR, all the code generation deps get bundled in.

Comment: How about excluding those transitive dependencies and the add explicitly with a scope?

Comment: Some clarifications are in order i think...your POM builds the JAR. The JAR has dependencies on other JAR's for Runtime, which any user of your library will need to know (i.e. the POM for the end users HAS TO define these). So, I am a bit lost when it comes to your wanting not to PUBLISH the transitive dependencies. Presumably you have one POM that you use to build the JAR and another you specify for the usage, no?

Comment: I mean if the question is to hide the transitives, then using the same POM for the end user community that you use for development, is something i would not do. I would separate the two usage contexts.

Comment: @AnveshVejandla: which scope is relevant? Other than `test` - which does not apply, its not a test code, and `compile` which publishes the dependencies, all the other do not download the deps at all.

Comment: @Beezer: In my project I have Java code that is only used to generate source code and is then never used in the runtime. What I want to achieve is that the code generation code and all of its dependencies are not exposed to (read: not dirty up) the dependency tree of consumers. This dual POM situation sounds interesting, but how do I get Maven to not use its the same POM when it deploys the library?

Comment: @Guss May be provided which is not transitive and is needed to mention in runtime if required. Also, I have a question why dont you exclude those transitive dependencies if not required and just add those which are required in runtime? May be I'm missing something. Can you correct me if I understood wrong?

Comment: @AnveshVejandla as far as I understand, `provided` means that Maven doesn't download them automatically, which is not what I want. I'm not sure how one "excludes dependencies".

Comment: I've added more details in my question, I hope its clearer now what my problem is.

Comment: Please show your full pom files or a link to your project..?

Comment: @Gus I would create another project for the consumers. Let's take Guava as an example. I am sure that Guava has dependencies. I am sure if you go to the Google Guava github, the POM will show that it has a lot of external dependencies. BUT, when I include Guava in my project, NONE of those build dependencies are exposed...i use gradle so the line is [compile 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0-jre']. Having said all that, I would create 2 POMs, one for the generation and jaring, and another for the dependencies for the end users and create a template project for those users.

Comment: When you build your Jar, and push it to your Nexus repo, you can also push a _subset_ of your POM for the usage. Why not? Maintain 2 POMs, one for operational use, and another for build usage...the latter being the superset of of the former....and as long as they co-exist in the same project, the build/CI/CD is all good to go. :=)

Answer (score 0):

What I did eventually was to create another POM just for the code generator, and use `maven-invoker-plugin` to run it during the main POM build.

So it looks like this:

- `generate-resources`: `maven-invoker-plugin` run `generator-pom.xml`

  - Invoked `generator-pom.xml`:
  - `generate-sources` : `maven-antrun-plugin` to create some resources for the generator
  - `compile`: `maven-compiler-plugin` compiles `src/generator/java`
  - `compile`: run generator to create sources in `target/generated-sources`
- `generate-sources`: `build-helper-maven-plugin` add-source `target/generated-sources`
- `compile`: `maven-compiler-plugin` compiles both `src/main/java` and `target/generated-sources`
- `test` ...
- `package` ...
- `deploy` ...

When Maven runs `deploy`, it only publishes the main POM file and `maven-source-plugin` only sees the main source directory and the generated source directory, so it doesn't collect the generator sources.

The `build-helper-maven-plugin`'s `add-source` action is important, because normally the code generator plugin adds the generated source's directory automatically to the build's source directory list, but because it is running in another POM, it can't do that - so I used build-helper to perform that task instead.

The main POM file looks like this:

```
...
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <pom>generator-pom.xml</pom>
            <showErrors>true</showErrors>
            <streamLogs>true</streamLogs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/mystuff</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version> <!-- needed to run JUnit 5 tests -->
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
```

(the generator POM refers to a lot of my company's closed source stuff, so no peeking there, sorry).